# Nest js npm run start failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, nestjs

I have installed fresh Nest js on new EC2 machine but when I am running it for the very first time it gives following error (**looks like npm install fails abrubtly whithout any visible error**) :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-190:~/projects/mynestjs$ npm run start:dev

> mynestjs@0.0.1 start:dev
> nest start --watch

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/projects/mynestjs/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands'
Require stack:
- /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/utils/local-binaries.js
- /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at loadLocalBinCommandLoader (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/utils/local-binaries.js:13:26)
    at bootstrap (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js:14:83)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js:25:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/lib/utils/local-binaries.js',
    '/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.10.0
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-190:~/projects/mynestjs$
```

It does not work with `npm run start` and `npm run start:dev` both.

While installing `npm install --silent` failed without any error.

I also checked and found that `package-lock.json` has not been generated.

Node js version is `v20.10.0`

NPM version is `10.2.5`

`nest -v` command returns error even though I had installed nest globally.

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "mynestjs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the environment variable for `NODE_ENV`?

Comment: Haven't setup Node_env upto now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use case, but it seems odd to use dev command in the EC2 container.

You don't need nest cli, just compile the code to js and execute it i.e.:
`node ./dist/main.js`.

You can use AWS CodePipeline to compile it with nest build and upload the artifact to the S3 to use it later in EC2.

The following video explains the whole process (with Elastic Beanstalk, which is based on EC2): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k731RVoQioU

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there are a few issues in your setup. Let's address them step by step:

1. Node and NPM Versions:
   The versions of Node.js and NPM you are using might not be fully compatible with the dependencies you have. NestJS 10.0.0 might have specific requirements.

Consider using a stable version of Node.js. You can switch to a stable LTS version. You can use nvm (Node Version Manager) to easily manage Node.js versions.

```
    nvm install --lts
    nvm use --lts
```

Also, consider upgrading NPM to the latest version:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

2. NestJS Version:
   It seems that the global installation of Nest CLI is not working properly. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall it.

```
npm uninstall -g @nestjs/cli
npm install -g @nestjs/cli@latest
```

3. Package Lock Issue:
   It's strange that the package-lock.json is not generated. This might be related to the previous issues. After fixing Node and NPM versions and reinstalling the Nest CLI, try running npm install again.
4. Nest CLI Version Mismatch:
   In your package.json, the version of @nestjs/cli is "^10.0.0", but in your error message, it's trying to find a module in node_modules/@nestjs/cli/commands. Ensure that the versions in devDependencies and the globally installed CLI match.
5. TypeScript Version:
   Ensure that the TypeScript version you are using is compatible with NestJS 10.0.0. You might want to specify the TypeScript version in your devDependencies.
6. Verify Installation:
   After performing the above steps, try running the NestJS application again:

```
npm run start:dev
```

These steps should help you resolve the issues you are facing during the installation and running of your NestJS application.